# Clarification regarding commit pulling terminology : Relationship with git cherry-pick and branches

Tags: git, github, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I am new to git related platforms, currently working primarily with github and gitlab on the side for project purposes. I have a confusion regarding an abstract terminology, it's related to fetching commits(perhaps unmerged or in different branch or from anywhere within a repo).

As far as I understand, we use cherry-picking when there are two branches(refactor,master) in a repository, and we want to pick a particular commit(X) out of one branch(refactor) and get in it another branch (master). (According to numerous sources out in the interweb)

Is it possible to cherry-pick within a same branch?  Is that even why cherry-pick exist?

Someone told me that cherry-pick does not have to do with branches at all, that abstractly "cherry-pick" in general stands for just picking any commit from anywhere (same or different branch)

Let me give an example scenario.

Let's say we have a master branch, and some people have sent some pull requests, which are yet to be committed, and someone wants to fetch those commits to test them before they get merged... I know how to fetch that commit, but my question is,  is doing that known as "cherry-pick"? That cherry-pick does not have to do with branches?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: If someone wants to test a branch, why wouldn't they just fetch and then checkout that branch?

Comment: Let's say, that they just want a single commit out of that test branch and check it out with other stuff in master which may not be available in the test branch.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to cherry-pick within a same branch? Is that even why cherry-pick exist?

No.

What you can do is:

- fetch the remote branch, referenced in your repo as `origin/master`
- create a test branch from your current `master` (unchanged because you didn't `git pull`, just `git fetch`)
- cherry-pick a commit from `origin/master` into `test`, for testing

In your case:

- [import your pull-request](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)
- checkout a test branch from your master
- do a simple merge from that PR branch (or a cherry-pick if want just a few commits of that PR branch)